# How do disable Windows (Vista) autoplay dialog for removable media

Tags: windows, autoplay

Whenever I insert a USB stick/external harddrive/CD/DVD an automatic dialog always comes up. It scans the media and tries to suggest programs to open the new files with.

I never use it. I would prefer if this dialog did not open. Is there a setting/shortcut key to prevent this? Hopefully there are both: setting for my computer, shortcut key for other computers.

Bonus: if it just opened up the new root directory/directories (D:\, F:) that would be great. That is usually what I end up doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HowToGeek provides yet another perfect walkthrough: [Disable AutoPlay in Windows Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-autoplay-in-windows-vista/). You can also set default actions here - ie, "open folder to view files in Windows Explorer".

Answer (score 2):

When you get the autoplay dialog there is both an option "Open folder to view files" and a checkbox "Always do this for foo". Ticking the checkbox and clicking the Explorer option should get you there.

Also you can set the default actions for each media type in the Autoplay settings (easiest found by just typing "autoplay" into the start menu).

Comment: I guess I dismmissed the autoplay dialog too quickly without even looking at it carefully... +1 for good answer, but Jared's answer is more complete